# CSS styles aren't applied to the pages

Tags: 7

On my site, CSS styles aren't applied to pages.
The site is working and I have no clue why this is happening.

> [image: Web Browser Console]

I have installed Nginx and php70-fpm on macOS El Capitan. I am using the configuration from drupal.org with a slight change.

```
server {
    server_name drupal.mac;
    root /Users/fabriziomazzoni1/nginx/drupal/;    
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
    location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
        allow 192.168.0.0/16;
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
        return 403;
    }

    # Allow "Well-Known URIs" as per RFC 5785
    location ~* ^/.well-known/ {
        allow all;
    }

    # Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
    # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
    # as Subversion or Git to store control files.
    location ~ (^|/)\. {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        # try_files $uri @rewrite; # For Drupal <= 6
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; # For Drupal >= 7
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    # Don't allow direct access to PHP files in the vendor directory.
    location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    # controllers other than update.php in a future release.
    location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
       root /Users/fabriziomazzoni1/nginx/drupal/;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
       #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
       include fastcgi.conf;
       $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
       fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
   }

    # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
    # location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ { # For Drupal <= 6
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ { # For Drupal >= 7
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

The server name is also set in the */etc/hosts* file in my local computer.

Comment: Do those GET links really have a space in them? If you add a space, can you access the file in browser? I'm pretty sure that after the ?, there shouldn't be a zero.. Switch off css and js aggregation in development>performance and report back.

Comment: Nope does not make a difference. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem. Deactivating Aggregation by drush  and clearing all caches finally solved my problem.

`drush -y config-set system.performance css.preprocess 0`

`drush -y config-set system.performance js.preprocess 0`

`drush cr`

Anyway, I think the problem is some wrong Nginx-Config detail.